# Insertar varios registros a la vez con ApiRestful - Laravel

Tags: laravel, json, api, restful

tengo la siguiente duda y quisiera que me ayudaran con esto, verán, tengo en mi controlador de subir equipos telefónicos a mi ApiRestful ya todo hecho para poder subir un equipo proporcionándole un "json", aquí el código:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $hash = $request->header('Authorization', null);

        $jwtAuth = new JwtAuth();
        $checkToken = $jwtAuth->checkToken($hash);

        if($checkToken)
        {
            //Conseguir el usuario identificado

            $user = $jwtAuth->checkToken($hash, true);

            //Guardar el auto

            $role = $user->role;
            if($role == 'SUPERUSUARIO')
            {
                //Recoger datos del post

                $json = $request->input('json', null);
                $params = json_decode($json, true);
                var_dump($params);

                $i = 0;
                $paramnew = [];
                foreach ($params as $param => $param_data) 
                {
                    $name_t[$i] = (!is_null($json) && isset($param_data['name_t'])) ? $param_data['name_t'] : null;
                    print_r($name_t);
                    $i++;
                }


                $name_t = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->name_t)) ? $params->name_t : null;
                $name_s = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->name_s)) ? $params->name_s : null;
                $marca = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->marca)) ? $params->marca : null;
                $marca_2 = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->marca_2)) ? $params->marca_2 : null;
                $modelo = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->modelo)) ? $params->modelo : null;
                $codigo_m = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->codigo_m)) ? $params->codigo_m : null;
                $busqueda = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->busqueda)) ? $params->busqueda : null;
                $color = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->color)) ? $params->color : null;
                $internet = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->internet)) ? $params->internet : null;
                $huella = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->huella)) ? $params->huella : null;
                $largo = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->largo)) ? $params->largo : null;
                $ancho = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->ancho)) ? $params->ancho : null;
                $grosor = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->grosor)) ? $params->grosor : null;
                $peso = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->peso)) ? $params->peso : null;
                $pantalla = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->pantalla)) ? $params->pantalla : null;
                $sistema = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->sistema)) ? $params->sistema : null;
                $version = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->version)) ? $params->version : null;
                $nucleos = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->nucleos)) ? $params->nucleos : null;
                $velocidad = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->velocidad)) ? $params->velocidad : null;
                $memoria = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->memoria)) ? $params->memoria : null;
                $sd = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->sd)) ? $params->sd : null;
                $ram = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->ram)) ? $params->ram : null;
                $cam_1 = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->cam_1)) ? $params->cam_1 : null;
                $flash_1 = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->flash_1)) ? $params->flash_1 : null;
                $cam_2 = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->cam_2)) ? $params->cam_2 : null;
                $flash_2 = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->flash_2)) ? $params->flash_2 : null;
                $bateria = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->bateria)) ? $params->bateria : null;
                $bandas_2g = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->bandas_2g)) ? $params->bandas_2g : null;
                $bandas_3g = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->bandas_3g)) ? $params->bandas_3g : null;
                $bandas_4g = (!is_null($json) && isset($params->bandas_4g)) ? $params->bandas_4g : null;

                if(!is_null($name_t))
                {
                    //Rellenar Variables

                    $telefono = new Telefono();
                    if(Telefono::all()->count())
                    {
                        $telefono_id = Telefono::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->id;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $telefono_id = 0;
                    }
                    $telefono->id = $telefono_id + 1;
                    $telefono->user_id = $user->sub;
                    $telefono->name_t = $name_t;
                    $telefono->name_s = $name_s;
                    $telefono->marca = $marca;
                    $telefono->marca_2 = $marca_2;
                    $telefono->modelo = $modelo;
                    $telefono->codigo_m = $codigo_m;
                    $telefono->busqueda = $busqueda;
                    $telefono->color = $color;
                    $telefono->internet = $internet;
                    $telefono->huella = $huella;
                    $telefono->largo = $largo;
                    $telefono->ancho = $ancho;
                    $telefono->grosor = $grosor;
                    $telefono->peso = $peso;
                    $telefono->pantalla = $pantalla;
                    $telefono->sistema = $sistema;
                    $telefono->version = $version;
                    $telefono->nucleos = $nucleos;
                    $telefono->velocidad = $velocidad;
                    $telefono->memoria = $memoria;
                    $telefono->sd = $sd;
                    $telefono->ram = $ram;
                    $telefono->cam_1 = $cam_1;
                    $telefono->flash_1 = $flash_1;
                    $telefono->cam_2 = $cam_2;
                    $telefono->flash_2 = $flash_2;
                    $telefono->bateria = $bateria;
                    $telefono->bandas_2g = $bandas_2g;
                    $telefono->bandas_3g = $bandas_3g;
                    $telefono->bandas_4g = $bandas_4g;

                    //Comprobar telefono duplicado
                    $isset_telefono = Telefono::where('name_t', '=', $name_t)->first();

                    if(count($isset_telefono) == 0)
                    {
                        //Guardar el registro
                        $telefono->save();

                        $data = [
                                'telefono' => $name_t,
                                'status' => 'success',
                                'code' => 200,
                                'message' => 'Telefono creado satisfactoriamente'
                                ];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $data = [
                            'status' => 'error',
                            'code' => 400,
                            'message' => 'El telefono "'.$name_t.'" ya existe.'
                            ];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $data = [
                            'status' => 'error',
                            'code' => 400,
                            'message' => 'Telefono no creado, el nombre comercial es requerido'
                            ];
                }

            }
            else
            {
                //Devolver error

                $data = [
                    'message' => 'Role insuficiente para hacer esta acción.',
                    'status' => 'error',
                    'code' => 300
                    ];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Devolver error

            $data = [
                    'message' => 'Hay que estar logeado para hacer esta acción',
                    'status' => 'error',
                    'code' => 300
                    ];
        }

        return response()->json($data, 200);
    }
```

Mi problema viene que para yo subir equipos no los subiré "1 x 1" sino que de un excel con todos los equipos que me pasa una compañía telefónica hago la conversión y vuelvo todo en un "json" parecido al siguiente:
[image: Json donde tengo el equipo y varios datos sobre el]
entonces con ese "json" ya creado quisiera que mi controlador de teléfonos subiese cada uno de los equipos que se encuentran ahí, he pensado en posibilidades, tal vez un foreach que repita cada uno de los "name_t" que seria mi llave foránea en la base de datos y por ende el único valor necesario para subir un equipo, porque todos los demás valores son opcionales, con solo poder subir ese valor a la base de datos pasandole un "json" donde hay muchos "name_t" y que me los tome como registros diferentes, me resolverían mucho la vida y ya yo me las arreglaría para que pasara lo mismo con los demás datos.

PD: si se preguntan porque en "$telefono->id" coloco un id de esa manera, es porque en la base de datos no es un campo "auto_increment", ya que no es mi llave única y no podía ponerlo como llave única ya que el mis teléfonos el "name_t" esta ligado a otra tabla de "precios"

Comment: EDIT: ignoren desde:
var_dump($params);
hasta la ultima llave del foreach de "params": 
$i++;
}
solo estaba probando cosas

Answer (score 1):

Mi solución fue la siguiente, para a quien le interese puede tomar de referencia, de esta manera subí el "json" de muchos teléfonos, haciendo un foreach de la información y se recorre "1 x 1"

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $hash = $request->header('Authorization', null);

        $jwtAuth = new JwtAuth();
        $checkToken = $jwtAuth->checkToken($hash);

        if($checkToken)
        {
            //Conseguir el usuario identificado

            $user = $jwtAuth->checkToken($hash, true);

            //Guardar el telefono

            $role = $user->role;
            if($role == 'SUPERUSUARIO')
            {
                //Recoger los datos por POST

                $json = $request->input('json', null);
                $params = json_decode($json);
                $params_array = json_decode($json, true);

                $i = 0;
                foreach ($params_array AS $param => $paramdata) 
                {
                    //Verificar el id del ultimo telefono existente   
                    if(Telefono::all()->count())
                    {
                        $telefono_id = Telefono::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first()->id + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $telefono_id = 1;
                    }

                    //Crear objeto $telefono
                    $telefono = new Telefono();

                    //Rellenar Variables
                    $telefono->id = $telefono_id;
                    $telefono->user_id = $user->sub;
                    $telefono->name_t = $paramdata['name_t'];
                    $telefono->name_s = $paramdata['name_s'];
                    $telefono->marca = $paramdata['marca'];
                    $telefono->marca_2 = $paramdata['marca_2'];
                    $telefono->modelo = $paramdata['modelo'];
                    $telefono->codigo_m = $paramdata['codigo_m'];
                    $telefono->busqueda = $paramdata['busqueda'];
                    $telefono->color = $paramdata['color'];
                    $telefono->internet = $paramdata['internet'];
                    $telefono->huella = $paramdata['huella'];
                    $telefono->largo = $paramdata['largo'];
                    $telefono->ancho = $paramdata['ancho'];
                    $telefono->grosor = $paramdata['grosor'];
                    $telefono->peso = $paramdata['peso'];
                    $telefono->pantalla = $paramdata['pantalla'];
                    $telefono->sistema = $paramdata['sistema'];
                    $telefono->version = $paramdata['version'];
                    $telefono->nucleos = $paramdata['nucleos'];
                    $telefono->velocidad = $paramdata['velocidad'];
                    $telefono->memoria = $paramdata['memoria'];
                    $telefono->sd = $paramdata['sd'];
                    $telefono->ram = $paramdata['ram'];
                    $telefono->cam_1 = $paramdata['cam_1'];
                    $telefono->flash_1 = $paramdata['flash_1'];
                    $telefono->cam_2 = $paramdata['cam_2'];
                    $telefono->flash_2 = $paramdata['flash_2'];
                    $telefono->bateria = $paramdata['bateria'];
                    $telefono->bandas_2g = $paramdata['bandas_2g'];
                    $telefono->bandas_3g = $paramdata['bandas_3g'];
                    $telefono->bandas_4g = $paramdata['bandas_4g'];

                    //Comprobar telefono duplicado
                    $isset_telefono = Telefono::where('name_t', '=', $paramdata['name_t'])->first();
                    $update_telefono = Telefono::where('name_t', '=', $paramdata['name_t']);

                    if(count($isset_telefono) == 0)
                    {
                        //Guardar el registro

                        $telefono->save();

                        //Devolverlo
                        $data = [
                                'status' => 'success',
                                'code' => 200,
                                'message' => 'Telefonos creados satisfactoriamente, ultimo telefono en ser subido: '.$paramdata['name_t']
                                ];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $update_telefono->update($paramdata);

                        $data = [
                                'telefono' => $paramdata['name_t'],
                                'status' => 'success',
                                'message' => 'Telefono actualizado satisfactoriamente',
                                'code' => 200
                                ];  
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Devolver error

                $data = [
                    'message' => 'Role insuficiente para hacer esta acción.',
                    'status' => 'error',
                    'code' => 300
                    ];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Devolver error

            $data = [
                    'message' => 'Hay que estar logeado para hacer esta acción',
                    'status' => 'error',
                    'code' => 300
                    ];
        }

        return response()->json($data, 200);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

El codigo de tu [solución](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/165053/57312) me parece que se puede optimizar muchísimo.

Desde el vamos no me queda claro como estas recibiendo el `$request->json` pero ***creo*** que tranquilamente podrías hacer

```
foreach ($request->json AS $param => $paramdata) {  }
```

Después no entiendo ese if que estás haciendo para obtener el **id**
Si lo definís en la migración como **`increments`** esté campo se autocompleta sin necesidad de que lo especifiques.

Además parece que los campos de tu json son iguales a los de la tabla por lo que directamente podrías hacer `Telefono::create($paramdata);` **(Asegurate que están como fillables en tu Modelo Telefono)**

Por ultimo si no puede haber un nombre duplicado en la migración colocale a tu campo **`name_t`** `->unique();`

**EL CAMPO ID DEBERÍA DE SER AUTOINCREMENT** `$table->increments('id');`
**EL CAMPO name_t DEBERÍA DE SER UNICO** `$table->string('name_t')->unique();`

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{
    $hash = $request->header('Authorization', null);

    $jwtAuth = new JwtAuth();
    $checkToken = $jwtAuth->checkToken($hash);

    if($checkToken)
    {
        // Conseguir el usuario identificado
        $user = $jwtAuth->checkToken($hash, true);

        // Conseguir el rol del usuario identificado
        $role = $user->role;
        if($role == 'SUPERUSUARIO')
        {
            // Recoger los datos por POST
            $params_array = $request->json; 
            // En la captura de pantalla pareciera ser 
            // que estás recibiendo todo en la llave **precios** 
            // así que quiza es $request->precios

            $data = collect(); // Creo que no es necesario

            foreach ($params_array as $param => $paramdata) 
            {
                // Crear Telefono Nuevo o Actualizar existente
                $telefono = Telefono::updateOrCreate(
                                      ['name_t' => $paramdata['name_t']], 
                                      $paramdata
                                    );
                $data->push($telefono); // Creo que no es necesario
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Devolver error
            $data = [
            'message' => 'Role insuficiente para hacer esta acción.',
            'status' => 'error',
            'code' => 300
            ];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Devolver error

        $data = [
                'message' => 'Hay que estar logeado para hacer esta acción',
                'status' => 'error',
                'code' => 300
                ];
    }

    return response()->json($data, 200); // Creo que no es necesario
    // Yo haría return response()->json(['message' => 'Success'], 200);
}
```

No considero un dato importante los registros cargados o actualizados ya que podrías hacer una consulta para obtener los telefonos por eso omitiría esa parte de coleccionar los telefonos.

No me quiero meter en el tema de autenticación asi que lo dejé igual, pero podrías usar un middleware en la ruta para verificar si el usuario está autenticado y otro middleware para verificar el rol del que dispone y en ese caso el método te quedaría:

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{
    foreach ($request->json as $param => $paramdata) 
    {
        $telefono = Telefono::updateOrCreate(
                              ['name_t' => $paramdata['name_t']], 
                              $paramdata
                            );
    }

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Success'], 200);
}
```

Comment: Te amo grosa! <3

Comment: jaja me hiciste reir. Me alegro que te haya gustado mi respuesta